# Is there any way to store the data in the logstash using post request?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, elk

I have a project that has microservices with different languages, I wanna store some data inside the logstash by post request, how can I do that?

It's not necessary to use requests, I just need a way that works with all servicies.

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to do? Logstash does not store anything, it is a tool to process data, not store it.

Answer (score 1):

You want the [Http input plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-http.html) for Logstash.

It will listen on a port and happily accept POST requests.